# load js file conditionally on view in keystone js/pug

Tags: javascript, pug, keystonejs

In keystone js you could do something like

```
if user && user.canAccessKeystone
            script(src='/keystone/js/content/editor.js')
```

to load a script if a certain condition is met. Would it be possible to conditionally load a script only in a certain view, i.e. in the "post" view?

something like this:

```
if view = post
    script(src='myscript.js')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that there is no need to load the script in the `default.pug` file. It can be loaded in the view file (i.e. `post-pog`) inside a `block.js` so that the script is loaded after the scripts in the `default.pug` file. Like this:

```
extends ../layouts/default
block content
  //-this is where the content of post.pug file lives
block js
  script(src='myscript.js')
```